# Creating a function which takes any number of functions as arguments

Tags: recursion, racket

I'm having trouble figuring out how to go about creating a function that can take a series of ***the same*** function as arguments with the last argument as an operand. For example:

```
(func sqrt sqrt sqrt 390625)
```

The call above should return 5 as (sqrt 390625) > (sqrt 625) > (sqrt 25) > 5

I'm having trouble figuring out the exact way I should write this as any way I have tried has given me errors or achieved an infinite loop.

This the code is have so far:

```
(define func
  (lambda L
     (cond ( (equal? (length L) 2)               ((car L) (cadr L)) )  ;; If the list consists of only 2 elements, carry out the function (element 1) onto the operand (element 2)
           ( #t                     (apply (car L) (func (cdr L))) )  ;; otherwise, apply the function (1st element) onto the rest of the list
           )
    )
  )
```

The first condition works, for example returning 5 if i call `(func sqrt 25)`, however the recursive call is throwing errors.

I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: If it's always the same function, why don't you receive the function `f` and the number of times `n` you want to apply it? it'll be easier, and makes more sense.

Comment: I know that would be the more sensical option but this was a question I had on a test some time ago that I struggled to answer, so I'm just trying to figure it out now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP doesn't provide a definition for `chain`, so that part is unclear, but I think that a fundamental problem here is that there is no recursive call to `func`; further, `apply` isn't used in the right position.

Instead of using `(equal (length L) 2)` as a base case, it might be nicer to make recursive calls as long as the first element in the input is a procedure, or otherwise just return the element:

```lisp
#lang racket

(define multi-call
  (lambda args
    (let ((arg (car args)))
      (if (procedure? arg)
          (arg (apply multi-call (cdr args)))
          arg))))
```

Here, when `arg` is a procedure, then it is applied to the result of calling `multi-call` recursively on the remaining arguments. Note that `multi-call` takes an arbitrary number of arguments, wrapping them in the list `args`. The reduction step provides `(cdr args)`, which is a *list* of the remaining arguments. This means that `apply` should be used to call `multi-call` on those remaining arguments because `multi-call` expects an arbitrary number of arguments, not a list of arguments.

```
multi-call.rkt> (multi-call sqrt sqrt sqrt 390625)
5
```